# Pass JSON Array to Spring Controller

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

I need to pass an array of an object to my controller. I'm trying to use @RequestBody like is described in the example here:

http://java2practice.com/2013/03/14/how-to-pass-json-object-string-or-jsonarray-string-from-javascript-to-spring-controller/

I've replicated the example in my project but I get a "bad request" error whenever I call it. I suspect this is because I'm using Spring 4 and Jackson 2 but I'm at a loss how to get it working.

Should this work in this environment? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the logs when the request fails?

Comment: @Steview try removing `dataType: 'json',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this should work in that environment (that is, using those versions of Spring and Jackson!). When faced with a mystery error like that my go-to is to crank up the log settings to TRACE for whatever library is failing.

I set up this example in my IDE (using Spring4 and Jackson2 as you are), and I immediately encountered a 400 "bad request" error as well. I cranked up the debug settings on `org.springframework.web` and `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` to find that Jackson2 was spitting out an exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of ca.ted.TestController$Person[] out of START_OBJECT token
```

This was because of the JSON being fed to the `jQuery.ajax()` call. I removed the `"persons":{}` object wrapping the array and sent only the array instead:

```
var arr = [ 
            {
                "firstName" : "Ramesh",
                "id" : "id1",
                "lastName" : "Kotha"
            }, 
            {
                "firstName" : "Sathish",
                "id" : "id2",
                "lastName" : "Kotha"
            } 
        ];
```

I did this but encountered the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class ca.ted.TestController$Person]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
```

Turns out this was because `Person` was an inner class in my Controller. I moved it out to its own file, `ca.ted.Person` and all was well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually I seem to have hit a new problem. The JSON is parsed successfully by the controller, but it always returns an error saying "not acceptable". The logs report: "Could not find acceptable representation"

Comment: Got it. This was because the example used the .htm extension which is apparently confusing my dispatchservlet. See: http://stick2code.blogspot.com.au/2014/03/solved-orgspringframeworkwebhttpmediaty.html

Comment: Ah! Nice catch. Glad I was able to help!